# JavaFX ListView duplicate removal error

Tags: listview, javafx, observable, observablelist

[link to imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/929e7.jpg)

```
@FXML
ListView queueList;

ObservableList<QueueSong> SongQueueObservableList;


queueList.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<QueueSong>,ListCell<QueueSong>>() {
    @Override
    public ListCell<QueueSong> call(ListView<QueueSong> myObjectListView) {
        ListCell<QueueSong> cell = new ListCell<QueueSong>(){
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(QueueSong myObject, boolean b) {
                super.updateItem(myObject, b);
                if(myObject != null) {
                    setText(myObject.getSong());
                }
            }
        };
        return cell;
    }
});

queueList.setItems(SongQueueObservableList);

SongQueueObservableList.add(new QueueSong("song 1", "artist 1"));
SongQueueObservableList.add(new QueueSong("song 2", "artist 2"));
SongQueueObservableList.add(new QueueSong("song 3", "artist 3"));
SongQueueObservableList.add(new QueueSong("song 4", "artist 4"));
```

I've tried the following implementations of removing

```
Platform.runLater( () -> {
       // queueList.getItems().remove(0);
        SongQueueObservableList.remove(0);
    });
```

The rows after the first duplicate are not selectable. And it's only once all the  values are removed from the list, that the `ListView` updates with an empty list.

If anyone has any tips on how to go about solving this, I'd appreciate it.

When I use the debugger, both the `ObservableList` and the `ListView` have the expected values. I guess the real question is, why is it that only when all objects are removed, that the `ListView` clears itself?

Comment: Can you add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the cell class you use. It only sets the text, but never clears it. Since it's possible that cells become empty, you need to fix this behaviour:

```
new ListCell<QueueSong>(){
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(QueueSong myObject, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(myObject, empty);
        // set text to song or clear (= set to null)
        setText((empty || myObject == null) ? null : myObject.getSong());
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have spotted this myself. Thank you so much.